# should I authenticate with every call to RESTHeart?

Tags: java, restheart

I want to write a messenger app on Swift, iOS and as a database I chose MongoDB and turned ON authentication on it. And for the bridge I chose RESTHeart([GitHub](https://github.com/softinstigate/restheart)). But for input something to database from RESTHeart I use the next line:

```
http PUT 127.0.0.1:8080/myfirstdb desc='this is my first db created with restheart' -a username:password
```

So, I use authentication for each connection. So my question is:

Is it OK, log in for each insert to database for the messenger app or there are another, better, solution? I think that I need to make this process as faster as possible

Comment: I'm severely tempted to remove the "`swift`" tag because this is a straight REST-ful API best practices question.

Comment: @Jens because RESTHear was written on Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the RESTHeart documentation:

> If a request is successfully authenticated, an authentication token is generated and included in every subsequent responses. Following requests can either use the password or the auth token.

http://restheart.org/docs/security.html

You have to enable the auth token with the `auth-token-enabled: true` configuration

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to ask you, how you can see in my request with httpie I send username:password. But it's not secure at all. Can you advice me, how can I send request without username and password of my MongoDB database?

Comment: You are welcome. This is a separate topic so I think you should open a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure to use https.

Quoting the RESTHeart documentation:

> With stateless basic authentication, user credentials must be sent over the network on each request. It is mandatory to use only the https listener; with the http listener credentials can be sniffed by a man-in-the-middle attack. Use the http listener only at development time and on trusted environments.